# Android Layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to represent a table. I have a parent container in a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and each row is further represented by a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation & weight of 100. I have used weight to ensure that the left side column and right side columns get 50% of screen width. But the columns on the right side are not properly aligned for some rows. What can I do to properly align them as in a table?

This is how my code appears for each LinearLayout row represented below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOM ID"
        android:id="@+id/tvBOMID" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etBOMID"
        android:hint="BOM ID"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: when you use `android:layout_weight`, use width as 0dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give 1-1 equal weight to TextView,EditText and set width as 0dp :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOM ID"
        android:id="@+id/tvBOMID" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etBOMID"
        android:hint="BOM ID"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, change the layout_width's to 0dp for the Layouts with weights, everything else looks fine. Any time you use a weight, set the width or height (whichever one is determined by the weight) to 0dp.

Answer (score 1):

in Android we have veryy good concept of Weight.

we give Weight To only in LinearLayout.

and We give Weight To the Layout Horizontally as well as vertical means in simple way we give weight layout height and Width.

in Weight You want To give a 0dp for the height or width which you want to give a weight.if you not give 0dp than its not affect to layout.

**Widht wise Weight...**

give 1 1 weight so textview takes  50 %and edittext 50% of total width of parent layout.

give 1 2 weight so textview takes  33.33% and editext takes 66.66% total width of parent layout.

give 1 3 weight so textview  takes  25% and edittext takes 75% total width of parent layout.

**Height wise Weight....**

give 1 1 weight so textview takes 50% and edittext 50% of total Height of parent layout.

give 1 2 weight so textview takes  33.33% and editext takes 66.66% total Height of parent layout.

give 1 3 weight so textview  takes  25% and edittext takes 75% total Height of parent layout.

**in your case** You want Width 0dp and weight is 1.

```
    **You just add this code**

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

below the code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BOM ID"
        android:id="@+id/tvBOMID" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etBOMID"
        android:hint="BOM ID"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

just change :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

in textview and edittext.